# Serialization-deserialization with Apache Thrift in nodejs

Tags: node.js, serialization, deserialization, thrift

I am working on a Node.js application and I need to serialize and deserialize instances of the structs defined in an .thrift file, like the following:

```
 struct Notification {
   1: string subject,
   2: string message
 }
```

Now this is easy doable in Java, according to the tutorial at http://www.gettingcirrius.com/2011/03/rabbitmq-with-thrift-serialization.html :

```
    Notification notification = new Notification();
    TDeserializer deserializer = new TDeserializer();
    deserializer.deserialize(notification, serializedNotification);
    System.out.println("Received "+ notification.toString());
```

But I can't find how this is done using the nodejs library of Thrift. Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, after wasting a lot of time on research and trying different solutions, I finally came to the answer to my own question:

```
//SERIALIZATION:
var buffer = new Buffer(notification);
var transport = new thrift.TFramedTransport(buffer);
var binaryProt = new thrift.TBinaryProtocol(transport);
notification.write(binaryProt);
```

where notification is the object I wish to serialize. At this point, the byte array can be found in the transport.outBuffers field:
    var byteArray = transport.outBuffers;

For deserialization:

```
var tTransport = new thrift.TFramedTransport(byteArray);
var tProtocol = new thrift.TBinaryProtocol(tTransport);
var receivedNotif = new notification_type.Notification();
receivedNotif.read(tProtocol);
```

Assuming that the following lines have been added to the index.js file from the nodejs library for thrift:

```
exports.TFramedTransport = require('./transport').TFramedTransport;
exports.TBufferedTransport = require('./transport').TBufferedTransport;
exports.TBinaryProtocol = require('./protocol').TBinaryProtocol;
```

Comment: If you want to deserialize in javascript in browser, take a look at: [thrift-js](https://github.com/amalakar/thrift-js). The repo contains files from the thrift node.js module but modified to work in the browser and examples.

Comment: How `new Buffer(notification)` is supposed to work? You're passing an object into constructor, there's no such overloads in Node. Also you don't need to modify `index.js` of thrift, because it's just `require('thrift/lib/thrift/transport')` etc.

Comment: @Clara For serialization data you pass `const notification = new Notification({ ... }); ` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my TypeScript version which runs in a browser. `npm install buffer` before use.

It should work on node if you remove `import { Buffer }`.

```
/*
 Thrift serializer for browser and node.js

 Author: Hirano Satoshi

 Usage:
    let byteArray = thriftSerialize(thriftObj);
    let thriftObj2 = thriftDeserialize(byteArray, new ThriftClass())
    let mayBeTrue = byteArrayCompare(byteArray, thriftSerialize(thriftObj2))
 */

import { TBufferedTransport, TFramedTransport, TJSONProtocol, TBinaryProtocol } from 'thrift';
import { Buffer } from 'buffer';

export function thriftSerialize(thriftObj: any): Buffer {
    let transport = new TBufferedTransport(null);
    let protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
    thriftObj.write(protocol);

    // copy array of array into byteArray
    let source = transport.outBuffers;
    var byteArrayLen = 0;
    for (var i = 0, len = source.length; i < len; i++)
        byteArrayLen += source[i].length;
    let byteArray = new Buffer(byteArrayLen);
    for (var i = 0, len = source.length, pos = 0; i < len; i++) {
        let chunk = source[i];
        chunk.copy(byteArray, pos);
        pos += chunk.length;
    }
    return byteArray;
}

export function thriftDeserialize(byteArray: Buffer, thriftObj: any): any {
    let transport = new TBufferedTransport(byteArray);
    let callback = (transport_with_data) => {
        var proto = new TBinaryProtocol(transport_with_data);
        //    var proto = new TJSONProtocol(transport);
        thriftObj.read(proto);
    }
    // var buf = new Buffer(byteArray);

    TBufferedTransport.receiver(callback)(byteArray);
    return thriftObj;
}

export function byteArrayCompare(array1, array2): boolean {
    if (!array1 || !array2)
        return false;
    let val = array1.length === array2.length && array1.every((value, index) => value === array2[index])
    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow i did not find the the byte array at:

```
transport.outBuffers
```

i needed to do the following:

```
         var transport = new Thrift.TFramedTransport(null, function(bytes){
            dataWrapper.out = bytes;
            cb(dataWrapper)
        })


        var binaryProt = new Thrift.TCompactProtocol(transport);
        notification.write(binaryProt) ;
        transport.flush() ; //important without the flush the transport callback will not be invoked
```